# Server won't boot when one RAID1 drive is removed

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, mdadm

I am fairly "green" when it comes to setting up RAIDs and LVM, but I can't work out why this setup doesn't work as intended. I have a server with two physical HDD's, upon which I'd like to setup things in a software RAID such that either drive can fail and the machine remain functional.

```
                                   +------+------------+
                                   | swap | / (root)   |
                                   | 5 GB | 113.5 ext4 |
                       +-----------+-------------------+
                       | /boot     | LVM               |
                       | 1 GB ext4 | 118.5 GB          |
+----------------------+-----------+-------------------+
| EFI system partition | RAID 1    | RAID 1            |
| 500 MB               | 1 GB      | 118.5 GB          |
+----------------------+-----------+-------------------+
| HDD (120 GB)                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

ie. both drives are configured identically, and the RAID's span both drives.

However, when I remove drive #1, the system boots to some state but tells me it cannot find my root LVM volume group and fails to come up fully. When I remove drive #2, the system cannot boot at all.

If more detail is needed I can provide it, but is there some fundamental design flaw with this configuration?

Comment: Is the EFI system partition also identical on both drives?  What is the output of `cat /proc/mdstat` both when it's working and when you pull drive #1 (you might have to boot from rescue disk for it)?  Also, did you pull drive #2 right after putting drive #1 back? the drives would need to rebuild before you can do that..

Comment: The output of `lsblk` and `fdisk -l` would probably help us a bit.

Comment: @DerfK Interestingly, `/proc/mdstat` doesn't exist. I configured this as part of Ubuntu's setup, and I assumed it was using `mdadm`. Clearly not 

Comment: @Zoredache Here's the output of those two while it's running with both drives https://gist.github.com/obeattie/8fed90cfa3dfb76ba5fcc24ccfe32f36

Answer (score 2):

So part of the problem, not booting at all when one of the drives is missing, probably means that bootloader didn't get configured on both drives.

Since this Ubuntu I think we can safely assume you are using grub?  If so run the command `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc`.  Leave most of the options as-is, what we want to change is the `GRUB install devices`.  Right now it probably has only `/dev/sda` selected.  Make sure both `/dev/sda`, and `/dev/sdb` are **both selected**.

Next problem. From  your output, it doesn't appear that your EFI partition is setup for any kind of RAID1.  So you might need to manually sync data to the second EFI partition.  I am not sure if you can setup a software based RAID1 for that.

I also don't have enough information to figure out why the LVM wouldn't be recognized with one disk removed.  When one disk is removed both RAID1 volumes show up as active in the `/proc/mdstat`?

Comment: You can do a software RAID 1 for an ESP volume. It must be of metadata version 0.90, as version 1.0 and onward store their metadata at the beginning of the disk (making reading an underlying member on its own less than workable). Simply create a small RAID 1 with metadata version 0.90, format it as an ESP volume (vfat) and it will work just fine. The EFI will read from the first one it finds and ignore any others. This way we don't have to perform a manual sync every time the EFI files are updated (which is close to never anyways).

Answer (score 0):

While it seems that a RAID 1 (mirror) setup should work with one drive missing, everything in this scheme depends on the method of RAID *control* in use.

There's two types of RAID from a controller standpoint - hardware-controlled, and software controlled.  Hardware controlled RAID is driven from a RAID controller chipset in the computer, such that the drives are managed at a lower level than the OS itself (usually from a BIOS level driver, such as offered by LSI).  Software-controlled RAID is managed by the operating system, usually a kernel-mode I/O driver that is set up to address two or more drives in tandem.

In the OP's case, there's a question that would need to be answered: In the system boot order/boot drive selection, is the RAID controller the only hard drive device chosen, or is one of the drives selected as the boot device?  If the former, then the RAID setup should work, as all drive access goes thru the RAID controller before reaching the drives.  The latter setup bypasses the RAID controller completely, and addresses the onboard controller on the drive itself... and this will break RAID.

I would recommend that the OP do the following if they are using a Hardware-based RAID controller scheme:

1. Boot into the BIOS, and ensure that Boot Order and Hard Drive
   selections do not address either of the RAID drives directly, only
   the RAID controller "virtual drive".
2. Go into the RAID controller setup (likely CTRL-C while its driver is
   being loaded on boot) and ensure that the drives are both
   selected as RAID drives and properly sync'd up.
3. Reformat the RAID 1 "drive" (technically a mirrored volume) and use it as
   the OS boot media.
4. Re-install the OS distribution such that it doesn't see two 'drives'
   but one 'volume' as its boot device.

IMO, software or OS-based RAID solutions are not recommended.

Comment: This is software-based RAID, I'm afraid.

Comment: I guess this is very subjective, and does not apply to all "HW RAID" controllers. It's often referred to as FakeRAID for a reason. If you lose your RAID controller, you may not be able to recover unless having spare one. In such case open format of software RAID is a great advantage - any Linux should work with it.